# How to show/hide DIV on selection of drop-down value with pure JS (no libraries)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have tide tables from several locations and each tide table is inside a div. Location is choosen from a dropdown menu. When the page opens it shows the first location tide table by default. When I change location, it selects the corresponding div and only shows the tide table inside that div, ignoring the other divs. It is working fine (thanks to @charlietfl), but using Jquery is causing problems with other parts of my homepage, so I am looking for a differet solution to achieve the same result.

This is what I have now:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
   $('select#location').change(function() {
   $('.box').hide().filter('.' + this.value).show();
   // set the value and trigger change on page load
   }).val('A').change()
 </script>

 <div>
   <select id="location">
      <option value="A">Location A</option>
      <option value="B">Location B</option>
      <option value="C">Location C</option>
   </select>
 </div>

 <div class="box A">Tide Location A</div>
 <div class="box B">Tide Location B</div>
 <div class="box C">Tide Location C</div>
```

Is there any way to get the same result, using pure JS (no libraries)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a code-writing service. You should explain what you have tried already, and where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your comment and I will follow your recomendation in my future posts. I have tried several solutions that dind't work at all but I didn´t mentioned them here to make it short, However I agree that I should have explained here what I have tried already and where exactly I got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following example

```js
document.querySelector("select#location").addEventListener("change", () => {
  display(event.target.value);
});

const boxs = document.querySelectorAll("div.box");

function display(value) {
  for (const box of boxs) {
    if (box.classList.contains(value)) {
      box.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
      box.classList.add("hide");
    }
  }
}

display("A");
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="location">
    <option value="A">Location A</option>
    <option value="B">Location B</option>
    <option value="C">Location C</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="box A">Tide Location A</div>
<div class="box B">Tide Location B</div>
<div class="box C">Tide Location C</div>
```

See

- [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Thank you so much. PERFECT! This is just what I was looking for! Problem solved! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS **display** property to the div

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```